# Paypal C# class for returning all transactions from Paypal

Tags: c#

Is there a way by which i can fetch the transaction history of my Paypal account into my application without having to log in to Paypal and checking it manually?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: actually i have just at their API n the web reference which they have provided to include in the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably accomplish what you want using the TransactionSearch method in the PayPal Merchant API, but it's probably not going to be a trivial undertaking.

Check out https://devtools-paypal.com/apiexplorer/PayPalAPIs and click on the "Merchant" tab to view the Merchant API methods. TransactionSearch is the fifth item on the list. They have an environment right on that page that you can play around with.

More info on TransactionSearch is available at: https://www.paypalobjects.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_transaction-search-and-details.html.

Then of course, you'll have to write the code to make the API calls and organize and display the data on your end.

Hope this helps!